# How to set the initial state of a variable from an api call in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Problem is:

--> Need to set the initial state of checkbox value from the api call, which would change after checkbox has been checked

--> I don't know how to set the initial state **before build method**

--> I can set it **after build method** but when I change the state in check box, widget is rebuild and it goes to the previous state from the api

```
class _EmailNotificationsPageState extends State<EmailNotificationsPage> {
 UpdateEmailSettingsDto requestDto = const UpdateEmailSettingsDto();
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getIt<SettingsCubit>().getSettingsDetails();
 }
bool emailMeAllNotifications = false; <-- I need to set this value from the api call above and change in build method

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 BlocBuilder<SettingsCubit, SettingsFetchState>(
    builder: (context, state){
      if(state is SettingsFetchLoaded){
        var data = state.data as SettingsResponse;
        var emailMeAllNotifications = settings?.sendToOwner; <-- I can set the state from api here
return _CheckBoxOption(
                 value: emailMeAllNotifications,
                  onChanged: (value) async {
                 setState(() {
                      emailMeAllNotifications  = value;
                    });
                }

              ),
      }
   }

class SettingsCubit extends Cubit<SettingsFetchState> {
final SettingsRepository settingsRepository;

SettingsCubit({
 required this.settingsRepository,
 }) : super(SettingsFetchInitial());

void getSettingsDetails() async {
 emit(SettingsFetchLoading());
 final successOrFailure = await 
 settingsRepository.getSettingsDetails();
 successOrFailure.fold(
      (failure) => emit(SettingsFetchError(failure.message)),
      (data) => {
        emit(SettingsFetchLoaded(data)),
       }
   );

  }
 }
```

Comment: 1. create two State named InitialSettingsState, LoadingSettingsState.
2. create new method in SettingsCubit, like  void fetching () async{ emit(InitialSettingsState); await getIt<SettingsCubit>().getSettingsDetails();  emit(LoadingSettingsState); }
3. call that fetching method from initState();
4. use  the States to to do ur fetching. like if State is Loading then show CircularProgressIndicator etc

Comment: pls can you help with example?

Comment: chek this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjCTNPKhgXc&list=LL&index=54

Comment: I am already doing that from the code provided above, I just need to update the checkbox state

Comment: can u share ur SettingsCubit code ?

Comment: Added the settingsCubit code

Comment: If you don't have the value to properly build something, you'll need to show a placeholder until then.  That's what FutureBuilder and friends are for.